# Material2 component not support in Angular2 RC4

Tags: angular, angular2-material

I am working on a project using angular2 RC4. I added the angular2-material third-party library. I imported some components, such as **button** and **toolbar**, adding them on the temple.  This looks successful, but when I added **menu** and **tabs** I got the error:

> menu.js and tabs.js is not found.

I checked path and files; everything is in place, just like **button** and **toolbar**.

I created one new demo project using angular RC5 and added angular2-material components, including **menu**, **tabs**, and **button**. This works perfect as expected.

Does Angular2 RC4 not support all Angular2-Material components, or I am missing something?

Can any one please rectify my question?

Comment: hi vijay you might want to look over this guide http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking question. which `version` of `@angular2- materia`l were u using with `@angular rc4` ?

Comment: Thanks for attention

Comment: Improved grammar and rhetoric